# Telerik RadBusyIndicator is not updating from MVVM ViewModel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, telerik

Initially RadBusyIndicatior is running , but when DoRefresh() called and Data has been updated , RadBusyIndicatior is still running , I have tried Two way Binding also ,  but no luck.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong . I just want to disable RadBusyIndicator once data has been loaded.

Xaml :

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadBusyIndicator Name="loading" IsRunning="{Binding ShowLoading}" Visibility="Visible" />
```

ViewModel Code :

```
 public class NewReleaseViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<NewRelease> NewReleases { get; set; }
    public NewReleaseViewModel()
    {
        NewReleases = new ObservableCollection<NewRelease>();
        showLoading = true;
    }

    private bool showLoading;

    public bool ShowLoading
    {
        get { return showLoading; }
        set { showLoading = value; 

            Set<bool>(ref showLoading, value); }
    }


    private RelayCommand _refresh;

    public RelayCommand Refresh
    {
        get
        {
            return _refresh ?? (_refresh = new RelayCommand(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await DoRefresh();

                    ShowLoading = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    ShowLoading = false;
                }
            }));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right overload of the `Set` method so the `PropertyChanged` event gets raised:

```
public bool ShowLoading
{
    get { return showLoading; }
    set 
    {
        showLoading = value; 

        Set<bool>(() => ShowLoading, ref showLoading, value);
    }
}
```